# Numerical integration of divergent functions

Tags: simulation, integration

I am having trouble with the numerical integration of a divergent function. For example,
\begin{equation}
n= \int f(x)\,dx = \displaystyle\int \dfrac{\Theta(x-\varepsilon)\,dx}{\sqrt{x-\varepsilon}}
\end{equation}
is not behaving good when calculated numerically:
\begin{equation}
n_\text{numerical} \approx f(x_j)(x_j-\varepsilon) + \sum_{k=j+1}^N f(x_k)\Delta x
\end{equation}
with
\begin{equation}
x_i = x_\text{min} + i\Delta x
\end{equation}
and $x_j$ being the smallest point larger than $\varepsilon$. Due to the divergent behavior of $f(x)$ near $\varepsilon$, the numerical result has discontinuities and jumps at every $\varepsilon=x_i$ when I sweep $\varepsilon$.
The smoothness of this integration is crucial in the convergence of my self-consistent simulations. Can anybody suggest a simple trick to solve the problem?

Comment: I must be missing something - why would you expect a *divergent* function to *not* behave badly when trying to evaluate it numerically?

Comment: Many divergent functions do have well-defined integrals. Also, all I need is to have a continuous numerical result by continuously changing $\varepsilon$.

Comment: Sure, but a well-defined integral does not imply that attempting to evaluate it numerically will work well! There are many tricks to avoid some of the more common problems. This might better be asked on one of the computer/algorithm sites.

Comment: I suppose you're just using Trapezoid rule for this?

Comment: The first order integrator doesn't work well even for well behaved functions. If you look at the error formulas for numerical integrators in general you will see that you always have to pick the step size such that none of the relevant higher derivatives becomes too large. In case of a pole that means you have to approach the pole with ever smaller adaptive step sizes that are chosen based on the function itself as you get closer. OTOH, there are probably much better semi-analytic solutions for this kind of problem available, anyway.

Comment: You need to specify the function $\Theta(\cdot)$ and the limits on the integral. Depending of those 'details', maybe it is feasible and maybe not.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Numerical integration of divergent function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1351734/numerical-integration-of-divergent-function)