# Solving $\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})$ using numerical integration, seems it is infinity

Tags: analysis

I know several different ways to prove that $\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})=\sqrt\pi$.

I made a simple FORTRAN program to calculate $\Gamma(x)$ using Simpson's rule, which worked fine for various integers and 3/2, 5/2, 7/2, etc.  However, when I tried $x=\frac{1}{2}$, the result was INF.  Which leads to my question...

Given $\Gamma(\frac{1}{2}) = \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt x}dx$,

how does this integral exist when limit of $\frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt x}$ as $x$ goes to $0$ is $\infty$ ?

Comment: By $\int_1^\infty\frac 1{x^2}dx$ existing...

Comment: You should do a variable change, similar to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1351741/331661)

Comment: Alternatively, use a rectangular integration, with the height being the value at midpoint: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum#Midpoint_rule

Comment: @abiessu: I think the question is about the lower limit $0$, not the upper limit $\infty$. But the answer is basically the same: $\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}} = \lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+} \int_\epsilon^1  \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}$ converges, so by the comparison test...

Comment: I don't think this works.  The gamma function is the integral from $0$ to $\infty$, you're only considering $0$ to $1$.  $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt x}dx$ diverges.

Comment: @HansLundmark the reason that the question integral exists is because the integral I listed exists and because the numerator in the question also converges rapidly. The comparison I am making is between $\int_0^1\frac 1{\sqrt x}$ and $\int_1^\infty \frac 1{x^2}$.

Comment: @DrBenway: The integral from $1$ to $\infty$ converges because of the $e^{-x}$ factor.

Comment: @abiessu: OK, I see.

Comment: @Hans Lundmark: Got it…thanks for the clarification